# Google Visualization API customization

Tags: api, customization, visualization

I'm making a website for school that involves a bunch of Google Visualizations. I can get them to work with the data I want, but I'm stuck customizing them. I have a very specific design I must follow, and it's not really working out at the moment.

The reason is that I don't know how to have two different styles on one element. For example :

```
legend: {textStyle: {color: '#d1dbbd', fontName: 'Century Gothic', fontSize: 15}},
legend: {position: 'bottom'},
```

This currently only positions the legend at the bottom. I'm trying to get these two in one line, but I don't know the proper syntax of the language (I've tried to find it online but to no avail. :(  )

I've shuffled it around a few times like so

```
legend: {position: 'bottom'}, {textStyle: {color: '#d1dbbd', fontName: 'Century Gothic', fontSize: 15}},
```

or

```
legend: {position: 'bottom', {textStyle: {color: '#d1dbbd', fontName: 'Century Gothic', fontSize: 15}}},
```

Help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are close with the format.  You want one object with "position" and "textStyle" properties:

```
legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
    textStyle: {
        color: '#d1dbbd',
        fontName: 'Century Gothic',
        fontSize: 15
    }
}
```